# What is the difference between getDefaultInstance() and getInstance() in Session class?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-mail

What is the difference between `Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator)` and `getInstance(props, authenticator)`?  In general, when will you choose one over the other?

I also read Java doc on [getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator)](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getDefaultInstance%28java.util.Properties,%20javax.mail.Authenticator%29), but still couldn't able to make out the difference distinctly/clearly.

Hope experts can help me in understanding this better.

**UPDATE:** Actual reason that triggered to ask this question is: We've used `Session.getDefaultInstance()` method in some places within our web-based application.  Sometimes, it throws `java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied`, on quick googling, it suggested to use `Session.getInstance()` method instead. Hence, when one would choose one over the other?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance(java.util.Properties) This doc might help you understanding difference

Comment: @org.life.java: I couldn't find any difference?  Can you point me to some specific sentence/para?

Comment: `getInstance()`: Get a new Session object. , `getDefaultInstance()` : Get the default Session object. If a default has not yet been setup, a new Session object is created and installed as the default.

Comment: @org.life.java: In real-time, when will one choose one over the other?  In my case, we've a web-based application and there are some contexts/places where emails will be fired.  Which method would be recommended in this case?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read the documentation, you will see that

**getDefaultInstance**
Get the default Session object. If a default has not yet been setup, a new Session object is created and installed as the default.

Therefore, if one does not already exist, it call getInstance()

**getInstance**
Get a new Session object.

So, a new session object is created, regardless of whether one already exists.

Comment: Actual reason for asking this question is explained here: We've used `Session.getDefaultInstance()` method in some places within our web-based application.  Sometimes, it throws `java.lang.SecurityException: Access to default session denied`, on quick googling, it suggested to use `Session.getInstance()` method instead. And that's the reason I've asked here when one would choose one over the other?

Comment: The only I reason I can see to use defaultinstance, is that it prevents the need to create multiple instances needlessly of the session, but other than that there is no difference. If you are having trouble with permissions, then just use getInstance(), it shouldn't cause you a problem. Your application however, should store this at a global level however, rather than create a new instance each time you need it.

Comment: Per doc, `getDefaultInstance(): Get the default Session object. If a default has not yet been setup, a new Session object is created and installed as the default.`, will subsequent calls to `getDefaultInstance()` just not make use of the session that was created before?

Comment: @Gnanam, yes, but it uses a shared instance across JVM's (reading between the lines in the documentation that says a session can be shared across the desktop). So, that is possibly why he is getting his error, that it is using a shared instance and accessing it with the wrong credentials. So, to prevent the error, it is safer not to use getDefaultInstance().

Comment: A very important side affect of using getDefaultInstance is that if the session is already created your properties you passed in will be ignored. The existing sessions properties will not be updated in any way, so if you're changing any properties you want to be using getInstance.

Comment: This is now covered in the [JAVAMAIL API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).

Comment: @Codemwnci i have a problem with line4 in your answer. i think if getDefaultInstance method calls getInstance method as you've mentioned, then this problem wouldn't exist. Could you clarify this for me?

Comment: Where are  saved the props?

Comment: will there be any performance impact if we use getInstance? as it is creating the new instance every time. If there the is a performance issue, are there any ways to handle it?

Answer (score 5):

FAQ says: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#getdefaultinstance

> Q: When should I use `Session.getDefaultInstance` and when should I
>   use `Session.getInstance`?
>
> A: Almost all code should use `Session.getInstance`. The
>   `Session.getDefaultInstance` method creates a new Session the first
>   time it's called, using the Properties that are passed. Subsequent
>   calls will return that original Session and ignore any Properties you
>   pass in. If you want to create different Sessions with different
>   properties, Session.getDefaultInstance won't do that. If some other
>   code in the same JVM (e.g., in the same app server) has already
>   created the default Session with their properties, you may end up
>   using their Session and your properties will be ignored. This often
>   explains why your property settings seem to be ignored. **Always use
>   `Session.getInstance` to avoid this problem.**

Answer (score 2):

Cause
This error is raised in the getDefaultInstance method in javax.mail.Session.java. According to this source code, this error occures when the default session object is already initialized, but authenticator instance is renewed or changed, or the class loader of the default session object is different from the argument authentificator's. Maybe the java source code using the default session instance of the java mail is recompiled and reloaded, or duplicate javamail class libraries are included into the Classpath of the environment.
 it gives proper solution

```
javax.mail.Session.java file
   public static synchronized Session getDefaultInstance(Properties props,
                                       Authenticator authenticator) {
       if (defaultSession == null)
           defaultSession = new Session(props, authenticator);
       else {
           // have to check whether caller is allowed to see default session
           if (defaultSession.authenticator == authenticator)
               ;       // either same object or both null, either way OK
           else if (defaultSession.authenticator != null &&
                   authenticator != null &&
                   defaultSession.authenticator.getClass().getClassLoader() ==
                       authenticator.getClass().getClassLoader())
               ;       // both objects came from the same class loader, OK
           else
               // anything else is not allowed
               throw new SecurityException("Access to default session denied");
       }

       return defaultSession;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was very important to use **`getInstance()`** instead of `getDefaultInstance()`.

Because after mail session properties was changed, mail session still was storing old properties.

So `getDefaultInstance()` - it is looks like Singleton.

As docs said:

> Note also that the Properties object is used only the first time this method is called, when a new Session object is created. Subsequent calls return the Session object that was created by the first call, and ignore the passed Properties object. Use the getInstance method to get a new Session object every time the method is called.

Comment: This key piece of information is in the documentation for getDefaultInstance(Properties, Authenticator) and not in that for getDefaultInstance(Properties).